# Concatenate two HTML inputs and insert them into a MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, web

I'm creating this web page for this class that I'm in and for it I need to concatenate two separate HTML form inputs with a space in between and insert them into a MySQL database. Specifically I ask the user for their first name and their last name in separate HTML form inputs and I have to concatenate those two input into a full name with a space in between (or else "Bob" and "Ross" concatenated would be "BobRoss" instead of "Bob Ross"). I don't know where to start when doing that. Also I need to check that the full name isn't already in the database before inserting it into the database, but I'm already doing that with the first name and last name so that shouldn't be too hard.

Here is the HTML page with the form inputs:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Site.css">
    <?php include("Header.php"); ?>
    </div>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>About</h1>

        <form action="Insert.php" method="post">
            <p>First name:</p><input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
            <p>Last name:</p><input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
            <p>Age:</p><input type="text" name="age"><br>

            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <?php include("Footer.php");?>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the PHP page where it inputs the data into the database. Currently I'm inputing the user's first name, last name, and age, but I need to concatenate the first and last name and make sure it isn't in the database and then insert it into the database and I haven't done that. Currently I make sure that the first name is unique, I make sure that the last name is unique, but I don't care whether the age is unique or not.

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","a7068104_user2","wiseguy1345");
if(!$con) {
    die("could not connect to localhost:" .mysql_error());
}

header("refresh:1.5; url=NamesAction.php");

mysql_select_db("a7068104_world") or die("Cannot connect to database");

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM names_1 WHERE firstname='$name'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
        echo "Your name is already in the database and will not be added again!";
}
else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO names_1 (firstname) VALUES('$name')";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if($result) {
            echo "Your first name was successfully added to the database!";
        }
        else{
            echo "Your first name couldn't be added to the database!";
        }
}

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM names_1 WHERE lastname='$name'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
        echo "Your name is already in the database and will not be added again!";
}
else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO names_1 (lastname) VALUES('$name')";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if($result) {
            echo "Your first name was successfully added to the database!";
        }
        else{
            echo "Your first name couldn't be added to the database!";
        }
}

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['age']);
    $query = "INSERT INTO names_1 (age) VALUES('$name')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result) {
        echo "Your name was successfully added to the database!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Your name couldn't be added to the database!";
    }

mysql_close($con);
?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Site.css">
    <?php include("Header.php"); ?>
    </div>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>Names</h1>
        <p>You will be redirected back to the <b>Names</b> page in a moment.</p>
        <?php include("Footer.php");?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for a start you don't need 3 INSERT queries  just 1 will do.

Comment: How would I do it with just one while checking that stuff is unique still?

Comment: you can simply use . operator to concatenate the 2 strings received using $_POST variable as `$sampleVariable = $_POST['month']."-".$_POST['year']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For a start you shouldn't be using `mysql` functions as this extension
>   is **deprecated** as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.
>   I suggest using the new improved [**PDO**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) library  and PDO Prepared Statements, see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

As for the concatenation, you could simply do it like this:

```
$concatenated_name = $_POST['firstname'] . " " . $_POST['lastname'];
```

This would concatenate the names with a space in between.

You can then use `$concatenated_name` in your queries.

However I still strongly recommend you use PDO for all your functions.

Comment: I know that the mysql_* series of functions are bad and that I should use the PDO library or the mysqli_* series of functions but for my class I needed to use the mysql_* series of functions. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

```
 $fullname = trim($_REQUEST['firstname']).trim($_REQUEST['lastname']);
```

Comment: That's great and I really appreciate it but how would I use $fullname to add the full name to the database?

Comment: you would not, just add the first name and last name in a two different fields. then when you do your select, do a concatenation. select concat(firstname,lastname) as fullname ......

Comment: That's not what I want to do though I want to add the full name in its own column to the database.

Comment: for what reason? if you have a column for first name and last name you already have it stored. The quick answer is add a field called fullname and simply insert the value with the $fullname = trim($_REQUEST['firstname']).trim($_REQUEST['lastname']);

Comment: I needed to do it for querying purposes.